# Changing width of textbox using css

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have css class like this:

```
.new-fld input[type="text"]{width:418px !important; margin-bottom:0px !important; height:18px !important; background-color:transparent !important; color:#FFF !important; border-bottom:1px solid #FFF; border-left:none !important; border-right:none !important; border-top:none !important; font-size:14px; /*padding:0 8px;*/}
```

It is applied to all the input filds on page.

I want some fields length to be different so I created another class like this

```
 .new-fld input[type="text"]{width:45px !important; margin-bottom:0px !important; height:18px !important; background-color:transparent !important; color:#FFF !important; border-bottom:1px solid #FFF; border-left:none !important; border-right:none !important; border-top:none !important; font-size:14px; /*padding:0 8px;*/}
```

and applied it like this

```
   <div class="new-fld">
                                        <input type="text" value="+44 1793 853219" name="">
                                          <input type="text" value="+ 44" readonly="readonly" name="Dialprefix1" id="Dialprefix1" class="dialprefix" style="text-align:right;width:45px;">

                                        <span>*</span>                                        
                                        </div>
```

As you can see, I entered width in textbox style but still it is not working.

but It is not working. Please suggest me good solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
 <input type="text" value="+ 44" readonly="readonly" name="Dialprefix1" id="Dialprefix1" class="dialprefix" style="text-align:right" size='10' />
```

and check the result.

OK, this will solve your problem (but I hope had a good reason to add !important to all styles):

```
<input type="text" value="+ 44" readonly="readonly" name="Dialprefix1" id="Dialprefix1" class="dialprefix" style="text-align:right;width:45px !important;">
```

Comment: what is your browser and what is your DOCTYPE ?

Comment: I tried this and it worked but not sure why: .smalltextbox input[type="text"]{width:45px !important; margin-bottom:0px !important; height:18px !important; background-color:transparent !important; color:#FFF !important; border-bottom:1px solid #FFF; border-left:none !important; border-right:none !important; border-top:none !important; font-size:14px; } and textbox like this : <span class="smalltextbox"> <input style="text-align:right" class="dialprefix" id="Dialprefix1" name="Dialprefix1" readonly="readonly" value="+ 44" type="text"></span>

Comment: I realy dont understand why you put !important to every style? CSS is cascade style sheet so it is cascade if you follow some simple rules you almost never require to use !important just for a few reasonale case. so you can remove all !important and your original code will work too.

Comment: whenever you see you are overusing !important be sure that there is something wrong with your code. so just do a noice clean-up and everything will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> **.new-fld input[type="text"]{width:418px !important;**

**

> .new-fld input[type="text"]{width:45px !important;

**

You have two class with the same name. you have to give the different name to it.

Comment: I tried this but didnt work:.dialprefix{width:45px !important; margin-bottom:0px !important; height:18px !important; background-color:transparent !important; color:#FFF !important; border-bottom:1px solid #FFF; border-left:none !important; border-right:none !important; border-top:none !important; font-size:14px; /*padding:0 8px;*/}

Comment: try to apply two different class to them with whatever style you want to apply it.

Comment: if you want to give different style to the textbox residing in the same div with class new-fld then you have to apply style to it explicitly. dont write !important  it will override your other styles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you havent simply declared different properties to the individual elements?
In your explanation and chosen answers, it seems to be the chosen method to set properties for the containing div?

aka:

```
.new-fld
{
    property:value;
}
```

## My Solution:

Why not give each input element their own id/class.
In your example you have given your 2nd textbox the following identifiers: id="Dialprefix1", class="dialprefix"

So you can set the properties as so:

```
#Dialprefix1
{
    size:22px; /* Change value (Width of box) */
    maxlength:22px; /* Change value (Max Accepted amount of chars in textbox) */
}
```

or assign the properties via the class declaration:

```
.dialprefix
{
    size:22px; /* " " */
    maxlength:22px; /* " " */
}
```

See for details on different properties that can be assigned to input fields.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Note: the prefix of "." in CSS tells the parser that you are refering to a class, whereas the "#" prefix refers to an id of that specific HTML element.